# this scope maintained when using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, this

I have an object that sets up some default properties

```
var Gallery = function(container, opts) {
 this.$innerWrap = null;
 this.innerWrapWidth = 0;
 this.$slides = $(el).find('img');
};
```

Now later on I have extended the prototype with another function to calculate the width of `this.innerWrapWidth` this is done by calculating all images inside of the `$innerWrap` and adding them together.

I have a problem however to do with scope this is my function:

```
Gallery.prototype.calcWrapWidth = function() {
 var that = this;

 $(window).on('load', function() {
  $.each(that.$slides, function() {
   var slide = $(this);
   that.innerWrapWidth += slide.width();
  });
  that.$innerWrap.width(that.innerWrapWidth);
 });
 console.log(this.innerWrapWidth)
};
```

Ideally I would to loop through all the images in array grab the widths and set it on the property `this.innerWrapWidth` and then add the value to `this.$innerWrap`.

I tried setting `var that = this;`

but when I run the console.log I get 0 returned as the value. I cant find the best way to set the final width on `this.innerWrapWidth`

**Update:**

I have narrowed it down! If I console.log out the `that` variable inside of the `window.load` function, I get the values I expect, but for some reason running `that.$innerWrap.width(that.innerWrapWidth);` doesn't set the width on the element. I can confirm that the inner wrap is definitely a jQuery object and that `innerWidth` is definitely an integer.

Comment: I don't think your issue has anything to do with `this` and `that`. (at least not that `this`...). Did you try `that.$slides.each(...)` instead? Not sure `$.each` does anything special to `this`. Also, where is `el` defined? Ans is this code executed when all the images exist?

Comment: This line: `this.$slides $(el).find('img')` is not an expression or a statement

Comment: Thanks @Tomanow I have updated that in the example

Comment: @FelixKling I did not but can try adding that.$slides.each. el is defined in that same object I was leaving it out for brevity.

Comment: @FelixKling I have tried doing `that.$slides.each` but still the value of `this.innerWrapWidth` is still 0. If I add a `console.log(that.innerWrapWidth)` inside of the each loop I see all the number I expect but it seems to to reset when it finishes

Comment: Uh wait... currently the `console.log(this.innerWrapWidth)` is *outside* of the event handler. That line will be executed **before** you are iterating over all the elements. However, `that.$innerWrap.width(that.innerWrapWidth);` should work just fine.

Comment: @FelixKling yeah just noticed that myself I have updated the original question with the new information. In short the .width() doesn't seem to be running

Comment: Where / when are you setting `$innerWrap`?

Comment: This question seems incomplete. As @FelixKling is implying, you're likely trying to set certain values after `Gallery` has been instantiated. If you don't want to post all your code, at least try adding a jsfiddle so we can see the problem itself.

Comment: @Jonathan  I have posted my code in a JSFiddle hopefully it will help get a clearer picture https://jsfiddle.net/wtm2ez2w/2/

Comment: Change `$(window).on('load', function() {` to `$(function() {` and change `this.$container.wrapInner(innerWrap);` to `this.$container.prepend(innerWrap);`.

Comment: To clarify, jQuery's `wrapInner()` function creates a new element, which means `that.$innerWrap` was pointing to an element that wasn't actually inserted. Also, `$(window).on('load')` isn't being triggered because by the time the code is reached, the `load` event has already been triggered.

Comment: this line :this.$slides = $(el).find('img'),should it be this.$slides = $(container).find('img');

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan but the reason I used wrapInner is because I need to wrap the img elements that are part of the code already and pretend will just create an empty tag at the beginning

Comment: @SamMason in that case, you need to `wrapInner()` _first_, and _then_ set `this.$innerWrap = $('.innerWrap-class');`.

Answer (score 0):

I appears that you should use below code sequence:

```
$(window).on('load', function() { 
  var myGal = new Gallery(..);
  myGal.calcWrapWidth();
});
```

and remove `$(window).on('load', function() {` code line from the `calcWrapWidth` method.

This assures that all elements are present on the page when your calculations are performed.

Comment: What is the difference between `window.onload` and `$(window).on('load', ...)` ?

Comment: So why are you suggesting to change that then?

Comment: True, this seems more reasonable, but it looks like it shouldn't make a big difference. Either way, I suggest to add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: Thanks for that @MaxZoom but I don't want to have to call separate methods when I instantiate the gallery, I think it would be better if it did it inside of the main call

Comment: @SamMason I am not sure what do you mean by `main call`, is it Gallery constructor?